# Redirecting url Using Google chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time working with javascript and chrome extensions. I wanted to append `?share=1` at the end of quora urls so i dont have to sign up. I made an attempt my looking at some answers but i am unable to find why this string is appended two times `?share=1?shared=1` at the end of my urls.

here is my code

### Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Quora view",
"description": "View quora without signing up ",
"version": "1.0.0",
"icons": {"128": "icon128.png"},
"background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "*://www.quora.com/*",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]}
```

### background.js

```
let host = "https://www.quora.com";
let post = "?share=1";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
     return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+[\S\s]*)/)[1] + post};
},
{
    urls: [
        "*://www.quora.com/*",
    ]
},
["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: I wrote it  like this `/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/` on my machine, but there was a typo while writing the question

Comment: Check if details.url.includes('?share=1') and don't return anything in that case?

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm it solved my error. But why did it appendind `?share=1` two times?